# InfluxDB: Interpretation of Inch Tool Output

Tags: influxdb

I have succesfully installed and running [influsDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/) server and relay. I am stressing the server through the relay using [Inch Tool](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/inch/#sidebar) from a client and the stress is also working fine.

But I am confused about what the each line int he log means. I will appreciate it if someone could thankfuly interpret it for me:

```
T=00001860 622140000 points written (62%). Total throughput: 334483.7 pt/sec | 334483.7 val/sec. Current throughput: 820000 val/sec. Errors: 0 | μ: 108.369368ms, 90%: 155.129377ms, 95%: 174.790982ms, 99%: 220.893544ms
```

I specifically would like to know what is after the 'Error' keyword means. Thank you

Comment: As described [here](https://github.com/influxdata/inch/blob/master/inch.go#L55) Errors mean "The current number of errors since last reporting."